# When to use @debug, @info, @warn, and @error in Julia

Tags: julia

There are currently four different error logging levels: "@debug, @info, @warn, and @error" all of which have a different use case and implications of their use. In general, when is it appropriate to use the different logging macros?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the docs:

```
@debug "Verbose debugging information.  Invisible by default"
@info  "An informational message"
@warn  "Something was odd.  You should pay attention"
@error "A non fatal error occurred"
```

Read more in the [Julia docs here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Logging/#Logging.@logmsg). In particular, it's important to note that `@error` does NOT throw an error, it merely logs an error and continues execution. If you want to throw an error, use the `error` function instead.

Comment: To make it useful, it would be a good idea to update this answer with short info how to set the visibility level for messages generated with those macros